# FastColoredTextBox line number background color

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to change the line number background color of the FastColoredTextBox control by Pavel Torgashov.

I have also done alot of research and cannot find anything about changing this.
Unfortunately it does not look to be as simple as changing a property.

[image]

Comment: The source code is online: https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox. have you tried cloning the repo and debugging the project? It looks like there's a `private Color lineNumberColor;`, but you may have to add to the project to expose a `private Color lineNumberBackColor;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indent back color is the color of the line numbers background.

Comment: Interesting, I was wondering what `indentBackColor` meant. Strange that it's not consistently named with `lineNumberColor`.

Comment: @RufusL mt thoughts exactly.